# ¿Como asignar un evento click a un botón en Android programáticamente?

Tags: java, android

estoy haciendo un modulo en Android y esta vez, cada que presione un Radiobutton (de muchos que hay en el formulario) debo agregar un EditText y un botón que tomará una fotografía y la almacenará en memoria física, ya pude agregar los elementos gráficos de forma dinámica, el problema es cómo asigno el evento click al botón de tomar foto siendo que este lo adiciono por código Java:

```
 public void AdicionarElementos(View view){
        LinearLayout contenedor = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
        EditText observacion = new EditText(this);

        observacion.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        observacion.setHint("Ingrese una observación");
        contenedor.addView(observacion);

        Button boton_tomar_foto = new Button(this);
        boton_tomar_foto.setText("Tomar Foto");
        boton_tomar_foto.setGravity(1);

        //Aqui asignar evento 
        //boton_tomar_foto............

        contenedor.addView(boton_tomar_foto);

    }
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Felipe, antes de agregar tu pregunta busca en el sitio, puede ser que tu pregunta ya este respondida en el sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programaticamente puedes agregar un escuchador al botón así:

```
 boton_tomar_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // tu acción
     }
 });
```

Comment: Genial! funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

tu codigo debe quedar asi

```
public void AdicionarElementos(View view){
    LinearLayout contenedor = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
    EditText observacion = new EditText(this);

    observacion.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    observacion.setHint("Ingrese una observación");
    contenedor.addView(observacion);

    Button boton_tomar_foto = new Button(this);
    boton_tomar_foto.setText("Tomar Foto");
    boton_tomar_foto.setGravity(1);
    contenedor.addView(boton_tomar_foto);
    //Aqui asignar evento
    //boton_tomar_foto............

    boton_tomar_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String file = "tuDirectorio" + Math.random() + ".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

        }
    });
}

int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería recomendable de no numerar el nombre del archivo en manera aleatoria, menos usando Math.random() y sin comprobar que el archivo ya existe. Un sello de tiempo da mejores resultados en generar nombres de archivos.

Answer (score 1):

se usa el listener [onClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) este tiene que estar configurado a tu view por medio de [setOnclickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).

```
Button boton_tomar_foto = new Button(this);

boton_tomar_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Aqui asignar evento 
            //boton_tomar_foto............

       }
  });
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en la documentación de **[Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)**.